# ExpressJS Dynamic routing and setting prefixes based on file name

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I am attempting to create a "Master Control" NodeJS server that loads the contents of my 'routes' directory and assigning them a prefix based off of the file name found in my routes directory.

So assume a file directory something like this:

```
.
├── _app
|   └──_routes
|      └──various routes.js (index.js, myApp.js, ...)
├── views
|   └── views...
|   
└── server.js
```

What would be the best way to go about loading all of the routes found in the routes folder (At runtime I won't know how many are in there or their names other than they will end in "Routes.js") and append a prefix to them based on the filename?

so the routes contained in myAppRoutes.js would be reached by

```
<server address>/myApp/<routes from myAppRoutes.js>
```

I've spent quite a while scouring here and npm and trying out various packages (dynamic-routes, express-routes, just to name a couple) all to no avail.

Though I don't think it makes a difference in this case, the node server is being hosted from an IBM iSeries machine.

node version - 0.12.12 (this is the latest available for IBM)
npm version - 3.10.3 (also latest available for IBM)

Comment: I somehow don't get it. What is your actual problem? Routes architecture?

Comment: Normally I would simply say something like var myRoute = require('myRoute.js') and then app.use('/myRoute', myRoute); However I am wanting to do that dynamically.

Comment: So, why can't you just list the files in the routes directory and load them all with require?

Comment: I'm not sure how to be more clear... I don't know the names of the files in the routes directory. And if I just require the routes directory I then have to add the prefix for a given route within that route. I'm wanting to do that at the app level.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? How come you don't know name of route's filename.

Comment: I'm trying to create a single server (I'll be using cluster once I get this working) so that as additional NodeJS applications are made they can share the same port, they only need to be listed in the routes folder of this app. I also don't want to have to force the use of a prefix at the route level. I would like when they are required for them to be assigned a prefix based on the filename.